# How can I pass different keyvault secrets to each VM I build using for_each expression

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I currently having a working script to build Windows servers in Azure using the for_each expression against a variable map. At the moment I’m using a variable for the keyvault secret but this is then used by all the vm’s being created. How can I pass different keyvault secrets to each VM I'm building.

Inside my module I have the following. I'm passing the value of the keyvault secret via the var.winserver.pw. I've created additional keyvault secrets but don't know how I would reference these when using a variable map. Any suggestions.

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "winservertest" {

  for_each = var.vm_map
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.m_resource_group_name
  location            = var.m_location
  size                = each.value.size
  admin_username      = var.m_admin_username
  admin_password      = var.winserver-test-pw
  patch_mode               = "Manual" 
  enable_automatic_updates = false 
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic-multi-vms-01[each.key].id
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it with the network `vms-01[each.key]` just like that we can change your pw to a map and do the same `var.winserver-test-pw[each.key]` your variable might have to change slightly to match the same keys as `vm_map` that is all ...

Here is an example we can test using random pet names

```
variable "vm_map" {
  default = {
    "abc" = {}
    "def" = {}
  }
}

variable "vm_pw" {
  default = {
    "abc" = "aaa"
    "def" = "ddd"
  }
}

resource "random_pet" "test" {
  for_each = var.vm_map
  prefix   = var.vm_pw[each.key]
}


output "test" {
  value = random_pet.test
}
```

that output will be:

```txt
Outputs:

test = {
  "abc" = {
    "id" = "aaa-composed-bug"
    "length" = 2
    "prefix" = "aaa"
  }
  "def" = {
    "id" = "ddd-sure-gar"
    "length" = 2
    "prefix" = "ddd"
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for being a bit thick :) Can you elaborate more. How would I reference an existing key vault secret in a variable map?

Comment: not sure about your question, I thought my answer and sample code cover that  ... `"abc" = "aaa"` there  `"abc"` is the key that matches with the vm map and `"aaa"` will be the secret

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to pass different keyvault secrets to each VM I build using for_each expression and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To do this, you need to write your Terraform configuration in a way that can automatically get the right secret for each VM.

To enhance the user experience of your requirement, I generated random passwords and stored them in the vault as secrets. Since secrets are sensitive information, I retrieved them from the vault using data modules and applied them to the VM configuration.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "vm_names" {
  description = "Names of the VMs"
  type        = list(string)
}

# Data source to fetch current Azure client configuration
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

# Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

# Network Interfaces for each VM
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  for_each = toset(var.vm_names)

  name                = "${each.key}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

# Azure KeyVault
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "demovkKVaultt"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                    = "standard"
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
}

# Azure KeyVault Access Policy
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Decrypt", "Encrypt", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Verify", "Sign", "Purge", "Release", "Rotate", "GetRotationPolicy", "SetRotationPolicy"]

  secret_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Purge"]

  certificate_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Purge"]
}

# Random Passwords
resource "random_password" "password" {
  for_each = toset(var.vm_names)

  length  = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

# Store the Random Passwords in Azure KeyVault
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  for_each    = random_password.password

  name         = "${each.key}-password"
  value        = each.value.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

# Azure Windows Virtual Machines
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "winservertest" {
  for_each = toset(var.vm_names)

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  admin_username      = "adminusername"
  admin_password      = azurerm_key_vault_secret.example[each.key].value

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example[each.key].id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

output "vm_ids" {
  value = { for vm in azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.winservertest : vm.name => vm.id }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here we can see that we have two unique secret passwords available in the vault, which help in creating two VMs.

**If you have your own predefined passwords stored in Azure KeyVault and to pass them to the VMs as passwords using Terraform**

Remove or comment out the `random_password` and `azurerm_key_vault_secret` resources for generating random passwords. Instead, use the `data "azurerm_key_vault_secret"` data source to fetch the existing secrets

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vm_passwords" {
  for_each    = toset(var.vm_names)

  name         = "${each.key}-password"  
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

and update the **`VM configuration module`** with

```
admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.vm_passwords[each.key].value
```

The rest of the configuration will remain the same.

Comment: Hello Vinay, thanks for the information. Another question how can I pass this from root module to child module? or would I create the keyvault secret in the child module.  admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.vm_passwords[each.key].value

Comment: Since I can't answer this here please raise a new  followup query mentioning your actual requirement so that I can provide the solution as per the requirement @wicker